# How to add a Service Reference from wsdl with DTD

Tags: visual-studio, wsdl, dtd, service-reference

In Visual Studio (C#, WinForms) I want to add a Service Reference from a `*.wsdl` file.
The underlaying `*.xsd` file imports other `*.xsd` files, one or more containing a `<!DOCTYPE... DTD.`
The 'Add Service Reference' function does not succeed and shows this error:

```
DTD is prohibited in this XML document.
```

How can I add the service reference?

##### To reproduce my problem:

Download the `.wsdl` files from:
https://github.com/gematik/api-telematik/tree/OPB5

The `.wsdl` file I want to add is located in: `conn\phrs\PHRService_V2_0_2.wsdl`

The `*.dtd` files are located in `.\ext`